# shibboleth SAML released attributes not in HTTP header

Tags: saml, shibboleth

I'm acting as a service provider in a Shibboleth SSO interaction.  I'm successfully getting back the SAML response with the expected attributes inside.  However, these attributes are not showing up in the /Shibboleth.sso/Session Attributes list.

I have the `<MetadataProvider>` tag in the shibboleth.xml file.  I'm wondering what else I could be doing wrong?

In the shibd.log I see the following:

```
skipping unmapped SAML 2.0 Attribute with Name: xxxx, Format:urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified
skipping unmapped SAML 2.0 Attribute with Name: yyyy
```

EDIT - I also added to **attribute-map.xml**:

```
<Attribute Name="xxxx" id="xxxx" />
<Attribute Name="yyyy" id="yyyy" />
```

The attributes do not have fully qualified names in the IdP's metadata.xml.  The names are just "xxxx" and "yyyy". Does this matter?

Finally, in the IdP's **metadata.xml,** they have this:

```
<saml:Attribute Name="xxxx" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"/>
<saml:Attribute Name="yyyy" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved it.  In the attribute-map.xml I had to add:

```
<Attribute name="xxxx" id="xxxx">
  <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="NameIDAttributeDecoder" formatter="$Name" defaultQualifiers="true"/>
</Attribute>
<Attribute name="yyyy" id="yyyy">
  <AttributeDecoder xsi:type="NameIDAttributeDecoder" formatter="$Name" defaultQualifiers="true"/>
</Attribute>
```

See here: [NativeSPAttributeDecoder](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPAttributeDecoder#NativeSPAttributeDecoder-StringAttributeDecoder)

Comment: so you should probably mark yours as answered :) but this custom NameIDAttributeDecoder is probably not very SAML2 standards friendly, OID should be the way to go

Comment: Oleg, it actually seems a bit clunky still.  Like sometimes it works and other times it doesn't.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

From [Shibboleth documentation](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/AttributeNaming):

> The SAML V2.0 LDAP/X.500 Attribute Profile specifies that X.500/LDAP
>   attributes be named by utilizing the urn:oid namespace. These names
>   are simply constructed using the string urn:oid followed by the OID
>   defined for the attribute.

So definitely you need to use OID for attribute names, attribute-map.xml has lots of examples.

For custom attributes that are specific to some IdP they will have to supply you with OIDs to use.

Comment: So my identity provider needs to provide them this way in his SAML response then? I'm wondering if I'm missing anything else configuration-wise on my end.  I have multiple MetadataProviders, although Shibboleth isn't having trouble finding this one at all.